# Bootastrap 3.3 tooltip in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of elements that i want to dynamically change its data-original-title. What i did was have a async function that returns that content and then displays using a tooltipp.
This is the code:

```
function onElementOver(el) {   
    var pos = el.getAttribute('data-pos');
    let contentTmp = arr[pos].content;
    if (!contentTmp) {
        let lat = arr[pos].lat;
        let lng = arr[pos].lng;
        getContent(lat, lng).then(function (ctn) {
            contentTmp = ctn;
            el.setAttribute('data-original-title', contentTmp);
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
            arr[pos].content = ctn;
        });  
    } else {
        el.setAttribute('data-original-title', contentTmp);
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    } 
}
```

I understand how the following line works, it gets all elements of the DOM wiht the data-toggle attribute, and displays it.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

What I need is to only display the data-toggle in the element el argument of the onElementOver function.

How can I get it to only show that specific tooltip?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking yet.  HTML would be helpful.  Instead of $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); you might try $(e).tooltip(); or $('?" + e).tooltip() depending upon what you are passing in there for e, an id, class, or jquery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it but i assume `$(el).tooltip()` will work. if el is already a jquery element then use `el.tooltip()`